# Django include template tag alternative in python class

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I know there is a Django template tag that allows to include other templates like so:

```
{% include 'template.html' %}
```

I am wondering if I could do the same, but in a separate python class (not in  the HTML template)?

I know that for example the url tag has an equivalent, like so:

```
{% url 'some_url_name' %} -> reverse('some_url_name')
```

Comment: what do you mean in a separate python class? your example is not clear

Comment: @petkostas I mean that could I do the equivalent but just not in a HTML template, since the HTML templates use different notation to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string).

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
context = {'foo': 'bar'}
rendered_template = render_to_string('template.html', context)
```